# View Rails record Associations in modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my Rails app I have 3 models `Kid`, `Classroom`, and `Teacher`. Basically, I have a table in my view which lists all the *classrooms*, when I click on a button I want a modal to pop up that lists the *teachers* and *students* assigned to that classroom, as there is an association where a `Classroom` has_many `Teachers` and has_many `Kids`. I have the code ready for the modal, I have copied it below, however I am having a difficult time scoping a specific *classroom* object to the modal. All help is appreciated!

```
<div class="modal fade" id="showClassModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 id="showClassroomHeader"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">  
        <h4>Teachers Assigned</h4>
         <ol>
          <% @classroom.teachers.each do |teacher| %>
            <li><%= teacher.first_name %> <%= teacher.last_name %></li>
          <% end %>          
         </ol>
         <br>
        <h4>Students</h4>
         <ol>
          <% @classroom.kids.each do |kid| %>
           <li><%= kid.first_name %> <%= kid.last_name %></li>
          <% end %>          
        </ol>    
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <% if current_user.admin? %>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" id="editClassroomBtn">Edit</button>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT:**

Classroom controller:

```
class ClassroomsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_classroom, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 # GET /classrooms
 # GET /classrooms.json
  def index
    @user ||= current_user
    if current_user.admin?
      @classrooms = Classroom.all
    else
      @classrooms = @user.classrooms.all
    end  
  end

  # GET /classrooms/1
  # GET /classrooms/1.json
  def show
    classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
    render :text => classroom.class_desc
  end

  # GET /classrooms/new
  def new
    @classroom = Classroom.new
  end

  # GET /classrooms/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /classrooms
  # POST /classrooms.json
  def create
    @classroom = Classroom.new(classroom_params)
    classroom.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
       if @classroom.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Classroom was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @classroom }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @classroom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /classrooms/1
  # PATCH/PUT /classrooms/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @classroom.update(classroom_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Classroom was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @classroom }
  else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @classroom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /classrooms/1
  # DELETE /classrooms/1.json
  def destroy
    @classroom.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to classrooms_url, notice: 'Classroom was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
 end

  private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_classroom
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
   end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def classroom_params
  params.require(:classroom).permit(:class_name, :class_desc, :capacity, :start_range, :end_range)
    end
end
```

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :rationales
  resources :teachers
  resources :classrooms
  resources :kids
  devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]

  as :user do
    get 'login' => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end

  root :to => 'kids#index'



 resources :kids do
  get 'discharge', on: :member
 end

 resources :kids do
   get 'restore', on: :member
 end


end
```

Comment: can you your controller and routes,id like to help

Comment: @mrvncaragay I have added my classroom controller and routes file

Comment: im guessing you're printing all `@classrooms` in index each with buttons to call the modal?

Comment: @mrvncaragay yes each have buttons too call the modal

Comment: then i think its ideal for you to create a partial in your view called `_classroommodal.html.erb` under `classrooms` and put your modal stuff in there

Comment: then i your view, when you're rendering the buttons render the partial like this passing an local variable `<%= render 'classrooms/classroommodal', classroom: classroom %>`

Comment: then in your modal you have a variable `classroom`

Comment: @mrvncaragay your idea works fine if I test with `<%= render 'classrooms/classroommodal', classroom: Classroom.first %>` for example, but how can I have it so that each row shows its own specific modal details?

Comment: Since it will pass an user object you can do it like this `<div class="modal fade" id="showClassModal<%= classroom.id %>" role="dialog">`

Comment: @mrvncaragay Still getting an undefined method error... what would the code be for the button? This is what I have now `<td><%= button_to 'Details', data: { toggle: "modal", target:"#showClassModal" }, class: "btn btn-xs"%></td>`

Comment: `target:"#showClassModal<%= classroom.id %>"` or give it an id `id="showClassModal<%= classroom.id %>"` either one will work. take a look at this https://github.com/mrvncaragay/HyraV2/blob/master/app/views/posts/_post.html.erb i used foundation reveal and it should be similar to modal.

Comment: @mrvncaragay I got that part to work, however the classroom object is still not picking up in the modal after button click ... any ideas?

Comment: Do you have your project in github?

Comment: Cant tell which part you're missing

Comment: @mrvncaragay Yes here is the link https://github.com/nomanshahid/GTLC/blob/master/app/views/kids/index.html.erb , the button is on line 198 and the modal starts on line 265

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120928/kidclassroom i created a chatroom

Comment: @mrvncaragay i need 20 reputation to chat ... only have 7 :(

Comment: its okay we can talk here

Comment: you have a ton of code in index i suggest separate the modal and make it as partial

Comment: but the problem is the modal should be inside   `<% @classrooms.each do |classroom| %> ...`

Comment: thats why i suggest use partial to make easier to work with

Comment: I see what you are saying, let me try it I will get back to you

Comment: @mrvncaragay the problem was the modal was not inside `<% @classrooms.each do |classroom| %>`, working beautifully now, thank you :)

Comment: awesome! write a short answer so you can mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section above, adding the modal inside `<% @classrooms.each do |classroom| %>` did the trick!